# ASP.NET OnServerClick and OnClientClick

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick

I am having some trouble figuring this one out

Here is my login.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="EcnManager.Web.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />        
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="height:30px">
                <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">ECN Manager Login</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form role="form" runat="server">                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtUserName" class="control-label">Login Name</label>
                                    <input id="txtUserName" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Login Name"/>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group has-error">
                                    <label for="txtPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
                                    <input id="txtPassword" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <%--<input runat="server" id="btnLogin" type="button" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnLogin_Click"/>--%>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" Text="Login" OnClientClick="btnLoginClick()" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemeberMe" runat="server" />
                                            <label class="text-center">Remember Me</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:30px">
                <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function btnLoginClick() {
                 alert("im here");
                 return false;
             };
        </script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run and click btnLogin i do get "im here" but it also goes and fire the server side event. I am passing false to btnLoginClick to prevent this from happening. Am i missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Yuriy Galanter answer did fix this. Thanks

Now i am trying to do jcalabris answer as well so that i can learn

so i did the following, not using asp button but an input of type button

```
<input runat="server" id="btnLogin" type="button" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
<%--<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" Text="Login" OnClientClick="btnLoginClick()" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />--%>
```

i changed my javascript code as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnLogin").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Is this correct, for me it did not work

I also tried the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnLogin").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

I think i am doing something wrong.

Appreciate your help a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return false in the button declaration as well.

Instead of

```
OnClientClick="btnLoginClick()"
```

try this:

```
OnClientClick="return btnLoginClick()"
```

Since your `function btnLoginClick` already returns false - the above returns that result to event, effectively canceling the postback

Comment: I see the `OnClientClick` fires, but our `OnServerClick` is not firing... why would that be? Is it a problem to use "return" in OnClientClick?